# NetBeans+Android: after update i have error: build.xml:77: Android Target is not set

Tags: android, netbeans, target

Today Netbeans found new update of android plugin. and i installed it. After that, all my project had "broken platform" instead of Android.2.3. I after i choose  platform again ,in project properties, it looks OK. But i can't build project - i get error
build.xml:77: Android Target is not set.

I did not change anything in my projects, now they just don't build..
any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this is bug of plugin, in build.xml.
Add to build.xml:

> `<property file="project.properties" />`

Comment: Wow! it was build.properties, i was blind! Now it works, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Adding "project.properties" brings up a new error:
Target "debug" does not exist in the project

Edit: I feel stupid now! :-)
Of course you have to update the android-sdk to revision 15 first.
http://www.nbandroid.org/ explains why.

Answer (score 0):

Update your Android SDK to recent version of Tools (revision 15 I think). Then update your project(s) as described in http://developer.android.com/sdk/tools-notes.html in a section related to tools revision 14.

There are few more comments on that at http://www.nbandroid.org/2011/10/synch-with-latest-android-sdk.html

-Radim

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Open project.properties file

and check if it contains

target=android-19

if not manually type this.